# How to use shortcuts that include modifier that is needed to get a character within the shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Let's say we have some shortcut `Crtl + Shift + /`. On some keyboard layouts `/` might be the primary character of a button, but on mine you need to use `Shift + 7` in order to write `/`.

Is there a way to still invoke `Crtl + Shift + /`?

I tried `Crtl + Shift + 7` as well as `Crtl + LShift + RShift + 7` but without getting anywhere, and I've had this problem on both Windows as well as Ubuntu.

(I am aware that you can change the shortcuts in most programs to something you like, but sometimes you can't or have some other reason not to change them.)